Why does the LSTM model generate identical predictions?
After training the LSTM model with time series data, I proceeded with predictions. However, I ended up with identical prediction results, as shown in the graph below.
enter image description here
I even performed hyperparameter tuning using Bayesian optimization, but nothing changed. Below is the code for the model I designed. The training data contains 26 features with a dataset size of 4,400. What should I modify to ensure that my LSTM model makes proper predictions?
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = int(unit_lstm1), return_sequences=True, dropout = dropout_1, input_shape= ( X_train.shape[1] ,1 )))  # 첫 LSTM 레이어
model.add(Dense(units = int(unit_dense1), kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=l1_1, l2=l2_1)))
model.add(LSTM(units = int(unit_lstm2), dropout = dropout_2, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(units = int(unit_dense2), kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=l1_2, l2=l2_2)))
model.add(Dense(units = int(unit_dense3), kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=l1_3, l2=l2_3)))  # 은닉층 추가
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=lr)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer)

optimizer_lstm =BayesianOptimization(f=lstm_cv, pbounds=params, verbose=1, random_state=1 ) 
utility_lstm = UtilityFunction(kind="ei", xi=0.05, kappa=None)
optimizer_lstm.maximize(init_points=10, n_iter=30, acquisition_function=utility_lstm)

I am attaching the code currently being used for parameter tuning, and please ignore the comments.
The graph shows the predicted values generated after completing hyperparameter tuning on the same LSTM structure.
I tried normalizing and standardizing the dataset, changing the LSTM model structure, and even switching the hyperparameter tuning package. I would like to understand the causes of the LSTM malfunction and the normalization process.
